# Regarding mailserver installation on IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008, mail-server

i tried to send emails from my ASP.net 4 application, it did not work!!
it worked only on hosting server. so i need to install a mail server on my server. the problem is that i have a small intranet with access to internet through a dynamic ip.
does installing of mail server on windows server 2008 requires static IP directly connected to the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can theoreticlly use a static-> dynamic ip service, but that is likely to be marked as spam very quickly. I would use google apps as a mail server. You can get google apps working on your own domain name, and if you can make due with 50 email accounts, it's also free! :)

Comment: For your reference: http://www.google.com/apps/

Comment: thanks Elad, do you have any idea how to setup my own mail server in simple steps or link to simple steps?

Comment: I worked off this: http://www.futureofrealestatetechnology.com/office-applications/how-to-setup-google-apps-for-your-domain/ The beauty of this setup is that you don't need to maintain a mail server. You use the gmail servers. This has the added advantage that you don't need to backup, compact, buy more storage when, etc. and also users can not only use outlook (or any other mail client), they can also logon using the gmail interface they already know and use, so there is almost no learning curve.